# Volley Content-Type header not updating

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to write a POST call in Volley, to send an XML body to the server. I cannot set the `Content-Type` header correctly.

The basic `StringRequest` looks like this:

```
StringRequest folderRequest =
        new StringRequest(Method.POST, submitInterviewUrl, myListener, myErrorListener)
    {
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
        {
            String body = "some text";
            try
            {
                return body.getBytes(getParamsEncoding());
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: "
                        + getParamsEncoding(), uee);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
        {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            return headers;
        }
    };
```

I override `getHeaders()` to supply the `Content-Type` header that I want - `application/xml`.

That is based on the suggestions questions similar to this one:

- [Android Volley Post Request Header not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022554/android-volley-post-request-header-not-changing)

---

When the request is sent, Volley has added a second `Content-Type` header automatically, so the headers look like this:

```
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

**How do I set the correct header?** Or remove the incorrect header?

I have tried tracing through the base `Request` code, but have been unable to find where this extra header comes from.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `Content-Type` header is not treated the same way as other headers by Volley. In particular, overriding `getHeaders()` to change the content type does not always work.

The correct way to do this is to override `getBodyContentType()`:

```
    public String getBodyContentType()
    {
        return "application/xml";
    }
```

I found this by looking at the code for the `JsonRequest` class.

Delyan also mentions it in his answer to this related question:

- [how to execute PUT request in Android Volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18027676/383414)

Comment: You saved the day, because as you mentioned, getHeaders() doesn't always work

Comment: Saved me, I was trusting the getHeaders will override the `getBodyContentType` provided value.