# Android - Volley Error 403 won't be solved

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I'm actually trying to create a login activity using volley but i can't understand why it always give me the `error 403 : unexpected response`.

I know that my php code is as good as my server because i tryed it with Postman and it work just fine.
(Internet permission is activated)

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText email,password;
private Button sign_in_register;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.25:80/tutorial2/user_control.php";
private StringRequest request;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    sign_in_register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_register);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    sign_in_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        if(jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SUCCESS "+jsonObject.getString("success"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class));
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" +jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                    if (error instanceof ServerError && response != null) {
                        try {
                            String res = new String(response.data,
                                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
                            // Now you can use any deserializer to make sense of data
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                            // Couldn't properly decode data to string
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (JSONException e2) {
                            // returned data is not JSONObject?
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashMap.put("email",email.getText().toString());
                    hashMap.put("password",password.getText().toString());

                    return hashMap;
                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the [screenshot of Postman.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E6Pu.png)

Comment: Post a screenshot of Postman which works. You might have given wrong Content-type or something else. 403 is a client side problem basically.

Comment: the photo is added

Comment: Are you setting `Content-Type` in your headers ?

Comment: what do you mean by setting that? how can i do that and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `Content-Type` in you request header like the example below. Just `@Override` `getHeaders` method.

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
{
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/form-data");
    return headers;
}
```

In case of header not updating, see this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26246558/3145960).

Comment: but maybe i didn't place it at the right spot. I put it after my hashmap who help me create the header. Or maybe it's because i just ctrl+c ctrl+v all. I need to change something in your code?

Comment: Nope I guess. You need to put this inside your `SigninRequest`.

Comment: what i saw by testing with log is that the onResponse function doesn't even start so i'm really stuck! Something missing but i can't tell what

Comment: my request is always http://192.168.1.25:80/tutorial2/user_control.php.
How can i put email and password in it? with the getHeader?

Comment: Reaz? you still here bro?

Comment: Yes I am here. What's now? :)

Comment: haha sorry to bother you but i don't really understand what's is the role of the getHeader

Comment: No problem. You are setting some specific things that you want to put in your Http request header in `getHeader` method. Like yo've set the `Content-Type` of your request to `form-data` because your API accepts the body in `form-data` format. If your API was expecting to have a JSON body you had to set `application/json` as your `Content-Type`. You can pass more additional parameters in your header too.

Comment: but i can't understand why error403
Myserver don't have a problem neither my php code;
so it must be my java code. I tryed to put **application/json** on **Content-Type** but it doesn't change anything.
With Log i saw that it does:
1-getParams
2-getHeaders
3-send me the error403
4-onErrorResponse

Comment: May be your header is not updating. See the answer attached with my answer. That might help you

Comment: @ReazMurshed how can i do the same for my problem here is my question :      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67874965/unexpected-response-code-403-but-work-fine-in-browser